# How can I make it so the x-axis values are not crossing each other?

Tags: plotting

The x-axis value seems to be crossing each other. How do I make it so it is more presentable?[image]

Comment: Put your code,not the picture.

Comment: Use `Ticks` to put fewer labels on the x axis `ListPlot[{{.00105,1},{.00115,20},{.00140,80}}, Ticks->{{.00110,.00120,.00130,.00140},{0,20,40,60,80}}]` so they do not overlap.